# Working with DataTables

Tags: c#, email, datatable

These are two records which exist in a table:

```
ibrahim_balouch
ibrahim.tasal
```

I want to send an email to ibrahim.tasal. Here is my code:

```
string user2 = dt1.Rows[1].ItemArray[0].ToString();
mail.Cc = dt1.Rows[1].ItemArray[0].ToString() + "@Roshan.af";
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Whats the question here? I dont see any question

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the particular column value of the first row of the datatable then something like this will help you

```
string user2 = dt.Rows[1].Columns["EmailColumn"].ToString();
mail.Cc = user2 + "@Roshan.af";
```

If you don't know the column name then you can specify the column index also which starts from 0.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The subject, which was to the effect of 'Hi, look at this code', has been changed. Nevermind.

Comment: Right. 'Hi, look at this code' was not a helpful subject title.